# Rich text editor not working on localhost server

Tags: javascript, html, markdown, pagedown, wmd-editor

I downloaded the [pagedown](https://github.com/balpha/pagedown) text editor and theWMD text editor, But they are misbehaving when i try to run them on the localhost server.

When i run it like this it works ok

> file:///D:/xampp/htdocs/myfolder/pagedown-master/demo/browser/demo.html
>
> i.e.
>   [image]

But when i run it like this from a localhost server it misbehaves

> http://localhost/myfolder/pagedown-master/demo/browser/demo.html
>
> i.e.
>
> [image]

How it misbehaves:

- The menu `...wmd-button-bar` hides its components and becomes blank
- The page does not stop loading

Its like it has something to do with the css path to the button image file

```
.wmd-button > span {
background-image: url(../../wmd-buttons.png);.....
```

Because when i delete the line the page will stop loading but still the buttons header will ofcourse not be there

Any help!

Comment: How are you running it from a local server, and from what location? Notice that the button image URL is a relative URL which backs up two directories (`../../`). If that is outside your server root, the server will not be able to find it. You need to at least run your server from the `demo` directory.

Comment: @Waylan even when i put it on the same directory and change the css to `background: url(wmd-buttons.png);` still wont work. so i resolved by using font awesome version https://github.com/micrum/awesome-pagedown